# ggplot2: plot all attributes per id

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a survey where each line represents a person and each column represents how long they took to complete the survey

I would like to plot a dot per timing per person so that if for example a person they completed the first part `x1` in 10 minutes and the second part `x2` in 12 minutes, the third part in 15 minutes `x3` and the fourth part in 45 minutes `x4` for ID 1 they would have these 4 dots on the y axis where the ID is the X Axis point

```
id <- sample(1:12)
x1 <- sample(1:250, 12, replace=F)
x2 <- sample(1:250, 12, replace=F)
x3 <- sample(1:250, 12, replace=F)
x4 <- sample(1:250, 12, replace=F)

mydf <- data.frame(id,x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

I tried using ggplot where i specified the x axis as the ID but im not sure how to represent all the other columns as different counts

Does anyone know if this is possible

Any help would be great

Comment: hi @mtoto, `set.seed()` doesnt really matter in this context because the aim is to map columns to a single X axis point in this case the ID of the user. I dont have ggplot code for it. If this was a regression problem it would be something like `id~.`

Comment: See answer, not sure if this is what you want though, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe we need to `melt` your `data.frame` first and then construct your desired plot.

```
library(reshape2)
melted <- melt(mydf, id.vars = "id") # Melt data
# Generate plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melted, aes(factor(id), value, colour = variable)) +
        geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much